# cakePHP Table Field naming convention

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, frameworks

So it seems that cakePHP tables need a field called "name" or else the id number is displayed while testing out table relationships in the scaffold.  Is there a way around this?  instead of  'id' 'name' 'last_name' in my table, I want 'id' 'first_name' 'last_name'.  I have to have a "name" field for every table in order to display the proper data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just set the $displayField property on your model class, just like the [manual says to](http://book.cakephp.org/view/105/Scaffolding)?

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel 
{    
    var $name = 'User';
    var $displayField = 'first_name';
}
?>
```